# Preview all raster within a date range from an Image Collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-2

I  am trying to preview all rasters separately within a date range from an ImageCollection and then export the required raster to a drive. As of now, I am doing this by changing the date range multiple times which is really time-consuming.

```
var dist = ee.FeatureCollection("users/tilok/aoi");
var s2=ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filterDate('2019-11-01','2020-03-31').select(['B2','B3','B4','B8']).filterBounds(dist).mosaic().clip(dist);
print(s2a);

Map.addLayer (s2a,{bands:['B8','B4','B3',],max:5000});
Map.centerObject(dist, 07);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: s2a,
  description: 'aoi_15mar2020',
  scale: 10,
  region: dist,
  maxPixels: 10e9
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with client-side iteration. The below script evaluate a client-side array with the collection image ids, iterate over the ids. For each id, the corresponding image is located from the collection, the image is added to the map and exported. You still have to click the `Run` buttons under the `Tasks` tab.

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 10]).buffer(1000)
Map.centerObject(aoi)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .limit(10)
  
collection.aggregate_array('system:index')
  .evaluate(function (indexes) {
    indexes.forEach(function (index) {
      var image = collection
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', index))
        .first()
        .clip(aoi)
      var description = 'image-' + index.replace(/[^\w]/, '_')
      Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B8,B4,B3', max: 5000}, description)
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: image.select('B4'),
        description: description,
        scale: 10,
        maxPixels: 1e13,
        region: aoi,
      });      
    })
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b2f24e621e4137248d719bc3bd9abd0b

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works. Thank you @Daniel